# Possible to use python packages inside Brownie scripts folder?

Tags: python, brownie

I tried to set up a Brownie project that looks like this

```
project
+- scripts
|  +- package_one
|  |  +- __init__.py
|  |  +- deploy_contract_one.py
|  +- package_two
|  |  +- __init__.py
|  |  +- deploy_contract_two.py
|  +- utils
|     +- __init__.py
|     +- helper.py
+- contracts
+- ...
```

where the deploy scripts import helper.py as `from utils import helper`. When I run a python script via the python executable, I can pass the -m flag to tell it the script is in a package, but `brownie run` doesn't have anything similar.

When I try to run either of my deploy scripts with `brownie run package_one.deploy_contract_one`, the error is `FileNotFoundError: Cannot find package_one.deploy_contract_one`.

If I try running with `brownie run package_one/deploy_contract_one`, then it can find my deploy script, but the error I get is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`.

Everything works if I move the deploy and helper scripts to the root scripts folder and use relative imports.

Is it possible for Brownie to run python scripts in packages, or do I need to restructure this project?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. If I put an `__init__.py` in my scripts folder and import my helper.py as `from scripts.utils import helper`, then I can run it as `brownie run package_one/deploy_contract_one`.

Additionally, if you installed brownie with `pipx`, you'll need to `inject` outside packages into your project.

So instead of

```
pip install matplotlib
```

It would be

```
pipx inject eth-brownie matplotlib
```